# Convert excel to XML in python

Tags: python, excel, xml, xsd

I am trying to convert excel database into python.
I have a trading data which I need to import into the system in xml format.

my code is following:

```
df = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/junag/Documents/XML/Portfolio2.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet1", dtype=object)
root = ET.Element('trading-data')
root.set('xmlns:xsi', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance')
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
Portfolios = ET.SubElement(root, "Portfolios")
Defaults = ET.SubElement(Portfolios, "Defaults", BaseCurrency="USD")

for row in df.itertuples():
Portfolio = ET.SubElement(Portfolios, "Portfolio", Name=row.Name, BaseCurrency=row.BaseCurrency2, TradingPower=str(row.TradingPower),
                          ValidationProfile=row.ValidationProfile, CommissionProfile=row.CommissionProfile)
PortfolioPositions = ET.SubElement(Portfolio, "PortfolioPositions")
if row.Type == "Cash":
    PortfolioPosition = ET.SubElement(PortfolioPositions, "PortfolioPosition", Type=row.Type, Volume=str(row.Volume))
    Cash = ET.SubElement(PortfolioPosition, 'Cash', Currency=str(row.Currency))
else:
    PortfolioPosition = ET.SubElement(PortfolioPositions, "PortfolioPosition", Type=row.Type, Volume=str(row.Volume),
                                      Invested=str(row.Invested), BaseInvested=str(row.BaseInvested))
    Instrument = ET.SubElement(PortfolioPosition, 'Instrument', Ticker=str(row.Ticker), ISIN=str(row.ISIN), Market=str(row.Market),
                               Currency=str(row.Currency2), CFI=str(row.CFI))


ET.indent(tree, space="\t", level=0)
tree.write("Portfolios_converted2.xml", encoding="utf-8")
```

The output looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDnI8.png)

While I need it to look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ee3YF.png)

How can I improve my code to make the output xml look better? please advise

here the excel data:
[image]

Comment: Please define "look better". What is the problem with the current output?

Comment: The child tag "Portfolio" belongs to "Portfolios" and "PortfolioPositions" belongs to "Portfolio". the problem is that for each portfolio position there is a separate start and end tag of "Portfolio" and "PortfolioPositions", while there should be one stat and end tag of "Portfolio" and one start and end tag of  "PortfolioPositions", and inside should be the positions.

Comment: For a [mcve], please post sample data. We cannot access your Excel file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need a single `<Portfolio>` and `<PortfolioPositions>` as parent grouping, consider a nested loop by iterating through a list of data frames. Then, within each data frame loop through its rows:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
import xml.dom.minidom as md

df = pd.read_excel("Input.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet1", dtype=object)

# LIST OF DATA FRAME SPLITS
df_list = [g for i,g in df.groupby(
    ["Name", "BaseCurrency2", "TradingPower", "ValidationProfile", "CommissionProfile"]
)]

# ROOT LEVEL
root = ET.Element('trading-data')
root.set('xmlns:xsi', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance')

# ROOT CHILD LEVEL
Portfolios = ET.SubElement(root, "Portfolios")
Defaults = ET.SubElement(Portfolios, "Defaults", BaseCurrency="USD")

# GROUP LEVEL ITERATION
for df in df_list:
    Portfolio = ET.SubElement(
        Portfolios, 
        "Portfolio", 
        Name = df["Name"][0],
        BaseCurrency = df["BaseCurrency2"][0], 
        TradingPower = str(df["TradingPower"][0]),
        ValidationProfile = df["ValidationProfile"][0], 
        CommissionProfile = df["CommissionProfile"][0]
    )

    PortfolioPositions = ET.SubElement(Portfolio, "PortfolioPositions")

    # ROW LEVEL ITERATION
    for row in df.itertuples():
        if row.Type == "Cash":
            PortfolioPosition = ET.SubElement(
                PortfolioPositions, 
                "PortfolioPosition", 
                Type = row.Type, 
                Volume = str(row.Volume)
            )
            Cash = ET.SubElement(
                PortfolioPosition, 
                "Cash", 
                Currency = str(row.Currency)
            )
        else:
            PortfolioPosition = ET.SubElement(
                 PortfolioPositions, 
                 "PortfolioPosition", 
                 Type = row.Type,
                 Volume = str(row.Volume),
                 Invested = str(row.Invested), 
                 BaseInvested = str(row.BaseInvested)
            )
            Instrument = ET.SubElement(
                 PortfolioPosition, 
                 "Instrument", 
                 Ticker = str(row.Ticker),
                 ISIN = str(row.ISIN),
                 Market = str(row.Market),
                 Currency = str(row.Currency2),
                 CFI = str(row.CFI)
            )

# SAVE PRETTY PRINT OUTPUT
with open("Output.xml", "wb") as f:
    dom = md.parseString(ET.tostring(root))
    f.write(dom.toprettyxml().encode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much!! this works perfect if I only have one portfolio. however when I am adding a second portfolio to the database, the code breaks. How can I make it iterate over portfolio attributes as well?

Comment: Please post sample data. With `groupby` it should work for all combinations of `["Name", "BaseCurrency2", "TradingPower", "ValidationProfile", "CommissionProfile"]`. Can any of these be missing with `nan`? If so use `dropna=False` arg in [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

Comment: Hi I added the excel screenshot into the post itself

Comment: What error are you getting? I fixed the save option with pretty print which was only issue with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Converting excel to XML in python

```
import openpyxl
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def convert_excel_to_xml(file_name, sheet_name):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_name)
    sheet = wb[sheet_name]
    root = ET.Element("root")
    for row in sheet.rows:
        for cell in row:
            ET.SubElement(root, "cell", value=cell.value)
    tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
    tree.write("{}.xml".format(sheet_name))
```

Run the function

```
convert_excel_to_xml("test.xlsx", "Sheet1")
```